fantasy book in which a girl discovers she has powers over water plants
I believe the book was a standalone novel and I think it was either teen or YA. I can only remember the cover and three specific scenes in the book.
First, the cover had a girl laying in a pond surrounded by water lilies. I believe she was wearing a pink skirt and a white shirt with bishop sleeves, but I could be wrong.
As for the plot, I know she discovered her powers because she was playing with some kids from her town by a river they aren’t supposed to cross because the forest on the other side is dangerous. Her brother falls in and she controls the water plants (they may have been water lilies specifically) to get him out. After she finds out she has powers, her and her father go to see the king to either help him with the monster problem in the forest or to just tell him about her newfound abilities. Her brother sneaks into the carriage so he accompanies them as well as one (or several?) knights, one of whom she falls in love with at the end. The second scene I remember is them hiding (or resting) in a room with dirt walls when someone tries to kidnap her? And the third thing is her and the knight love interest having a heart to heart about his backstory.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a hardcover, paperback, or e-book?

@DavidW around 5 years ago and it was hardcover
